# bokeh development workflow with interaction

Tags: bokeh

I'm developing a visualization using

```
% bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

The problem is that when I change `myapp.py` I have to kill the above command and restart it. Is there a better workflow for this kind of development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to understand enough of the bokeh internals to make this work nicer, but here is a hacky script that does what I want anyway.

```
# bokeh_watcher.py
#
# Watches specific files in directory and restarts bokeh server upon change.
#
#   % python bokeh_watcher filename.py
#
# Note that you stil have to navigate your browser to localhost:5006/filename
# to see your Bokeh visualization and you might have to refresh the browser. 

import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import RegexMatchingEventHandler
from bokeh.command.bootstrap import main
import multiprocessing
import os
JOBS = []
FILE = []

def spawn_bokeh(args):
    main(args)

class BokehHandler(RegexMatchingEventHandler):
    '''
    kills and restarts bokeh server upon filechange.
    '''
    def on_modified(self, event):
        super(BokehHandler, self).on_modified(event)
        what = 'directory' if event.is_directory else 'file'
        logging.info("Modified %s: %s"% (what, event.src_path))
        p=JOBS.pop()
        p.terminate()
        time.sleep(1) # time to die
        logging.info('terminated')
        logging.info('initiating restart')
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=spawn_bokeh,
                                    args=(self.args,))
        p.start()
        JOBS.append(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    here = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    fullpathname=os.path.dirname(here)+os.sep+sys.argv[1]
    # local logger
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    filemod_handler = BokehHandler(['.*%s'%(sys.argv[1])])
    filemod_handler.args = ['','serve',fullpathname, '--log-level','info'] 
    # fire up bokeh server
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=spawn_bokeh,args=(filemod_handler.args,))
    p.start()
    # store object in global for later
    JOBS.append(p)
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(filemod_handler, '.', recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. As of Bokeh `0.11.1` (and soon to be `0.12` too), this is a planned, but still open, [feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4236) There are only a few folks working a huge pile of work for Bokeh. New contributors can help accelerate new features and fixes. If you're able to help, please reach out to us on the [project gitter channel](https://gitter.im/bokeh/bokeh).